# Android get ArrayList from Room Database in adapter class

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-room, android-livedata

I have a Room Database table with multiple columns (*PartsTable*). I need to fetch only one column from the table that contains one word String and I'm using a subset of a table as per google docs (*PartsTuple*).

Now I need to create a function that will or something else that will return the ArrayList of fetched data, which I can access in my adapter class. I am able to return the data and see it in a console log (from the main fragment where I get data from ViewModel), but I just can't seem to make it work on a function that will return the said list of data which I could then access from a different class.

Code from DAO:

```
@Query("SELECT keyword FROM partsTable")
LiveData<List<PartsTuple>> getTuple();
```

Code from repo:

```
public LiveData<List<PartsTuple>> getPartsTuple() {
return partsKeyword;
}
```

Code from view model:

```
public LiveData<List<PartsTuple>> getPartsTuple() {
    return partsKeyword;
}
```

Fragment class where I display data in a log:

```
mViewModel.getPartsTuple().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<PartsTuple>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<PartsTuple> partTuple) {
            Log.d(TAG, "vraceno: " + partTuple.toString());
        }
    });
```

, and data from the log

> D/PartsFragment: vraceno: [part1, parts3, part_2]

Code from adapter class where I compare strings and highlight them.

```
ArrayTEST arrayTEST = new ArrayTEST();
        ArrayList<String> values = arrayTEST.getWordFromHardcodedList();

        String text = note.getPartsSubtitle();
        Spannable textSpannable = new SpannableString(text);

        for (int j = 0; j < values.size(); j++) {
            //word of list
            String word = String.valueOf(values.get(j));
            //find index of words
            for (int i = -1; (i = text.indexOf(word, i + 1)) != -1; i++) {
                //find the length of word for set color
                int last = i + word.length();
                
                textSpannable.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#1a0cab8f")),
                        i, last, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                textSpannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED),
                        i, last, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
        }
        if (note.getPartsSubtitle().trim().isEmpty()) {
            tvTEXT.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            tvTEXT.setText(textSpannable);
        }
```

The part that I'm having trouble with is this, where I need to get a list of data from database and not hardCoded like this

> arrayTEST.getWordFromHardcodedList();

Now **I need to access this list of data from my adapter class** since if there is a match I wanna highlight the parts from the list of parts in my main recycler view where all the data is shown. I can do this when I type the list manually but it needs to be dynamic based on user input.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using shared preferences with Gson.

In app gradle add

> ```
> implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
> ```

Save the data to SP in a fragment:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = requireActivity().getSharedPreferences("shared_preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = gson.toJson(myListOfData);
            editor.putString("partsKEY", json);
            editor.apply();
```

Load the array in the adapter class:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("shared_preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = sharedPreferences.getString("partsKEY", null);
        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<NoteTupleTest>>() {
        }.getType();
        partsArrayList= gson.fromJson(json, type);
        if (partsArrayList== null) {
            partsArrayList= new ArrayList<>();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter class add a field for this list - I'll call it `highlightedParts`. Observe `getPartsTuple()` as you do, and set the data you get to `highlightedParts`. Then you need to create a custom setter for `highlightedParts` and every time it gets called, update elements of the `RecyclerView` to highlight the desired items. For updating, you can use `notifyDataSetChanged()` method. There are other, more optimized variations for only updating a specific item or item range, but you're going to have to update entire dataset.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, will try to do it like that, but that seems to take a whole different route of looking at this problem. I'm using liveData and my adapter class extends ListAdapter so I'm doing highlighting on the go every time the main recycler view is called. I updated my question with code from the adapter so you can check it out.

Comment: Let me know how it goes and if you need additional help.

Comment: Will do, thanks.